# Difference between pausing and resetting a game Spritekit / Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Right now I've got it where if I click on the pause button I've made, it goes to my pause menu. When I go back to the game screen via the button I made to do that, the game has reset itself to the beginning.

I've got a "go back to the game button" and a reset the game button.

How do I get those two to act correctly?

I don't even really know where to begin with this because I don't know if the game is clearing when I'm initially leaving the screen or when I'm going back to it. I thought I had read the default behavior was to save the state of a screen when you navigated off of it.

Comment: I believe Apple Docs state that if you keep a reference to your scene, it will persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change your game view controller (gameVC) to your menu view controller (menuVC), if there isn't any reference remaining everything gets deallocated. Therefore, when you go back to your gameVC you're allocating new objects (scene, nodes, ...).

What you might be looking for, to pause your game, is the `paused` property.

On your `SKScene` (which is a SKNode) : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/paused

> paused
>
> A Boolean value that determines whether actions on the node and its descendants are processed.
>
> If the value is YES, the node (and all of its descendants) are skipped when a scene processes actions.

On you `SKView` : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKView/paused

> paused
>
> A Boolean value that indicates whether the view’s scene animations are paused.
>
> If the value is YES, the scene’s content is fixed onscreen. No actions are executed and no physics simulation is performed.

*The `update:` method won't be called if the SKView is paused.*

Comment: Ah okay awesome.  When I do this though it prevents the navigation from happening. It pauses the scene but does not send me to my paused screen, and obviously then nothing on the screen works because it's paused. Any idea how to work around that?

Comment: As mentioned above by  _Epic Byte_ you could keep a reference of your scene (and probably pause it once you arrive on your pause menu). Then you'll have to load that scene instead of a new one. Another possibility is the one you've mentioned : store the game state then load it afterwards (ex: game level, nodes positions, ...).

Comment: Alright cool deal. Lasssst question and the one I was initially scared of asking lol... how exactly do you keep a reference of the scene (first project ever so just learning as I go)? I assume it's quite simple, if not I can make a separate question if needed if you don't want to go through it here.

Comment: You could have a property `var storedGameScene : GameScene` within your menuVC. Before transitioning to it, in `prepareForSegue` for example, you set it with your current game scene.